# Attach event to dynamically created chosen select using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-chosen

I want to add event to dynamically created chosen select and want to get option value..
but confuse how to fire event on dynamically created chosen select...?

I know we can use `jquery.live or jquery.on event` but for that we need proper selector/id

```
$(document).on( eventName, selector, function(){} );
```

My fiddle : [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4wCQh/20/)

html :

```
<select id="t1pl1" class="chosen-select" data-placeholder="Select player..." style="width:200px;">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="11">Player 1</option>
    <option value="12">Player 2</option>
    <option value="13">Player 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4wCQh/23/

I think you can use `on` for event binding and since you have dynamic elements, you should use the parent selectors of `select` for event binding.

Simple solution will be to use this:

```
    $(document).on('change', 'select[id^="t1"]', function () {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
```

Use this code for updation:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', 'li.active-result.highlighted', function (e) {
   $("#pid").html($("option").eq($(this).data("option-array-index")).val());
});
```

instead of your old code.

**Explanation:**

`change` is the event, `select[id^="t1"]` is the css selector for all the select having id starting with `t1`. Refer [Attribute Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) for more information. Further you can get the current value of `select` using `$(this).val()`

Comment: How are you getting the value in $('#pid') ? What is the logic behind it?

Comment: actually team has 11 players so there are 11 constant chosen select box but if user wants to add more player/referee then he will enter how many persons he wants to add in $("#t1pladdcount") text default is 1

Comment: $("#pid") contains option value using this value i want to show photo of player or referee later on option hover/mouseover event

Comment: Okay, check the updated answer. See if it works for you.

Comment: it conflicts as my page has many chosen select box....so i added "player" class to each select tag...

Comment: i used `$(document).on('mouseenter', 'li.active-result.highlighted', function (e) {
      var currentText = $(this).text();
      showplayer ($(document).find("select.player option").filter(function () { return $(this).html() == currentText; }).val())
    });`

Comment: Better give a common class to the select. I just displayed how it is done. You can modify accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid juggling with IDs attach your listeners to the selector itself.

```
// Do your selectbox creation...
// var selector = whatever...

$( selector ).on( eventName, function( event ){
    console.log( 'Event was triggered by', $( event.target ) );

    // do stuff with your event.target, like getting value and such.
});
```

Comment: selectors are not known in advance i am adding it dynamically so how can i use jquery.on event ?

Comment: Are you creating your selectboxes via jquery?